# Android Camera Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, camera

I'm using the following xml code for my camera layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/preview" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
        android:text="Click" android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />

</FrameLayout>
```

When the user clicks the screen it will capture the image.

Now what I want to do is to have another button in the same view to launch my image viewer, how to do this? I want something like this (image viewer button on the lower right corner):

[image]

Many thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a button and set android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"

Comment: I mean, I already tried adding android:layout_gravity="right|bottom", but still not work for me. You mean you tried it and work for you?

Comment: <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/preview" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
        android:text="A" android:layout_gravity="center" />
  <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonClick1"
        android:text="B" android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />
</FrameLayout>

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a button with a custom background. On the click method you need to implement a new intent like this.

startActivity(new Intent("[here is your imageViewer's package name]");

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I can do that but the problem is how will I show the button on top of the frameview?